# IL Call with Method from string

Tags: c#, reflection.emit

I've been trying to create my own toy programming language for CIL using IL Reflection to generate the exes, but when Im calling a method I just doesn't seem to work.

I am using `System.Reflection.ILGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Call, MethodInfo)`.

When getting the `MethodInfo` from a `Type` gotten by using the `typeof(something)`, it works fine, the call is sent through and it works, but when I get the `Type` with the `Type.GetType(string)` function, for some reason it won't generate the IL, I have tested and found that the `typeof == Type.GetType` (there is no difference in the result when checking with the `==` operator).

I have looked around but can't seem to find any solution, can anyone tell me what's happening?

EDIT:
[here is a link to the git repo file](https://github.com/Northcode/nvm/blob/master/nvm2/compiler/ILGenerator.cs)

Code:

```
//Create IL Generator and standard stuff before this...
ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, "hello world"); //Push argument(s)
MethodInfo method = typeof(Console).GetMethod("WriteLine", new Type[] { typeof(string) });
MethodInfo rmethod = Type.GetType("System.Console").GetMethod("WriteLine", new Type[] { typeof(string) });
if(method == rmethod)
{
    Console.WriteLine("MATCH!"); //This fires so I know they match
}
ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Call, method); //This works
ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Call, rmethod); //This does not... (no exceptions, but no code is generated looking with ILSpy afterwards)
```

Comment: Post full code of dynamic method. how do you pass argument etc

Comment: there, don't see what differance it makes though, the arguments are emmitted fine btw.

Comment: This is impossible to explain.  Other than noting that Type.GetType() should only ever be called with the *fully-qualified type name*.  If you give a partial name like "System.Console" then accidents can happen.

Comment: No, there has to be an explanation. How does this sample behave under Mono? If it is the same, can we look in the source to see if the Equals method does warranty that both instances actually are equal?

Comment: Could you create add short, but complete sample code that demonstrates this? There's lots of code that's irrelevant to this question in the file you linked to.

Comment: I have boiled down the problem to be this, but I can't find any workarround, there is really not much more code I can provide than what is in the post, I edited in how I add the arguments but the souldn't make any differance cause they work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem, at some point in my code before this was executed, the typebuilder.CreateType was fired, and this stoppes the il generation...

Thanks for the help though!